# App crashes when I want to use tableview.deleteRows(at: , with: )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I already saw many topics on this subject but I still have the error...

Here is my code in the tableview delegate method (is called when the user swipe and click on the delete button on the cell):

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()

if self.data[sectionType]!.isEmpty {
    self.data.removeValue(forKey: sectionType)
}

self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

I have implemented the numberOfSections delegate method like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
```

And this is the error I get:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView internal bug: unable to generate a new section map with old section count: 1 and new section count: 0'

I get the same error if I replace deleteRows(in tableView) method by reloadData()...

I checked with breakpoint, I enter in the if condition when the error occured. So the data is updated (0 element after the removeValue() call) and I call the deleteRows method.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you use the numberOfRowsInSection method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to delete a row or a section?

```
if self.data[sectionType]!.isEmpty {
    self.data.removeValue(forKey: sectionType)
}
```

Suggests you are trying to delete a section. If you are it should be followed by something of this sort:

```
let indexSet = NSMutableIndexSet()
indexSet.addIndex(section)
self.tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, withRowAnimation: .fade)
```

If you are trying to delete a row then change the top part to something like this:

```
if self.data[sectionType]!.isEmpty {
    self.data[sectionType].remove(at: rowToRemove)
}
```

Comment: You'r totally right ! I wanted to delete a section. I didn't use the right method of UITableView. deleteSections() method fixed my issue :)
Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be deleting all your rows in the section, instead of the one cell.

I'm assuming `self.data` is a dictionary where the keys are sections and the the values are arrays containing cell information.
Instead of deleting the key to the dictionary. Like you have here...

```
self.data.removeValue(forKey: sectionType)
```

You might want to access the section and remove just that row. Something like this...

```
data[sectionType]?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
```

I assume the return value you have for the method `numberOfRowsInSection:` is something similar to...

```
return data[sectionType]?.count
```

Hope this helps in someway.